# Translate SQL Groupby + Sum to C# lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I working on ASP.NET core w/EF project about donation, I would create a donation list group by founder and order by the total amount.

It is simple to query 2 table [DonationTransaction] and [Aspnetusers] by SQL:

```
SELECT CONCAT(u.FirstName, " ", u.LastName) as Fullname, 'BuddyIcon.jpg' as Image, SUM(t.amount)
FROM donation_transaction t
LEFT JOIN aspnetusers u 
ON u.Id = t.user_id
```

GROUP BY t.user_id
    Order By SUM(t.amount) DESC

However, by using repo pattern w/ EF, I have to query by lambda expression.

```
IEnumerable < DonationTransaction > tranlist = _donationTransactionService.GetDonationTransactions();
IEnumerable < Aspnetusers > userlist = _userService.GetUsers();
IEnumerable < DonationRanking > founderlist = tranlist.Join(userlist,
  t => t.UserId,
  u => u.Id,
  (t, u) => new {
   UserID = u.Id, FullName = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName, Image = "BuddyIcon.jpg", Amount = t.Amount
  })
 .GroupBy(grp => grp.UserID)
 .Select(group => new DonationRanking {
  Name = group.First().FullName,
   Image = group.First().Image,
   TotalAmount = group.Sum(ta => ta.Amount)
 })
 .OrderByDescending(dr => dr.TotalAmount);
```

I have some question:

1. I have preview the query result, the result is seem correct, however I don't understand why taking the group member by First() method (e.g. group.First().FullName), 
   base on [MSDN document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535050(v=vs.110).aspx) 
   First() method - Returns the first element in a sequence that satisfies a specified condition.
   So does it mean getting the first row from [grp] only? 
   How to improve the lambda expression above?
2. By Visual Studio 2017, it able to visualize the SQL generate by LINQ in debug mode, however it can't inspect if using lambda Expression, another interesting things I found is, whatever I enable the SQL profiler on MySQL.
   The SQL generate by lambda expression won't be log.
   So how can I preview the SQL like use LINQ2SQL?